# Android: Endless Scrolling listview content error and NullpointerException

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-asynctask, cwac-endless

I have huge problems fixing endless scrolling with product loading from JSON and loading the images from products. I get two errors which I can't fix I have tried everything I could.

It sometimes loads pages when I'm not on the last item that gives me a "Adapter changed but listview wasn't notified error" and I get a random NullPointerException which says nothing to me and I can't solve it. Any help?

Error Nullpointer:

```
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at com.tonika.productlijst$ImageLoaderTask.onPostExecute(productlijst.java:761)
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at com.tonika.productlijst$ImageLoaderTask.onPostExecute(productlijst.java:1)
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at com.commonsware.cwac.task.AsyncTaskEx.finish(AsyncTaskEx.java:422)
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at com.commonsware.cwac.task.AsyncTaskEx.access$300(AsyncTaskEx.java:129)
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at com.commonsware.cwac.task.AsyncTaskEx$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTaskEx.java:434)
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
03-27 10:25:29.250: E/AndroidRuntime(23494): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Error content has changed:

```
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131165198, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class android.widget.SimpleAdapter)]
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1996)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
03-27 10:26:48.515: E/AndroidRuntime(23630): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
public class productlijst extends Activity {
    ListView list;
    String keuze = "nothing";
    String filter = null;
    ImageView search;
    ImageView thumb;
    int kf;
    int c;
    int o;
    int set;
    int currentpagee;
    int products;
    int check;
    int working;
    View footerView;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    TextView total;
    TextView current;
    TextView divider;
    ImageButton back;
    ImageButton next;
    DownloadTask downloadTask;
    ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask;
    ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> mylist;
    ProgressBar prog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.productlijst);

        //Get Bundle
        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (extra != null) {
            filter = extra.getString("keuze");
            keuze = extra.getString("filter");
        
            Log.i("keuze", filter);
        }

        thumb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imPThumb);
        search = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imSearch);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvKeuze);
        prog = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbProductLijst);
        mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

        prog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       
        downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        DownloadPage downloadPage = new DownloadPage();

        c = 0;
        o = 10;
        currentpagee = 1;
        kf = 0;
        products = 0;
        check = 0;
        working = 0;

        // Starting the download process
        downloadTask.execute("http://no.nl/api/products?display=full&limit=" + c + ",10&filter[id_category_default]=" + filter);
        downloadPage.execute("http://no.nl/AppScripts/GetCount.php?cat=" + filter);
        
        list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {}

            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (working != 1) {
                        if (list.getLastVisiblePosition() >= list.getCount() - o) {
                            Log.i("Scroll", "scroll " + c);
                            if (c >= products ) {
                                //load more list items:
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Geen producten meer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                working = 1;
                                check = 1;
                                kf = 1;
                                c = c + o;
                                currentpagee++;

                                //current.setText("" + currentpagee);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Producten Laden..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                ScrollDownloadTask scrollDownloadTask = new ScrollDownloadTask();
                                scrollDownloadTask.execute("http://no.nl/api/products?display=full&limit=" + c + ",10&filter[id_category_default]=" + filter);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nog bezig met laden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    /** A method to download xml data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String line = null;

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(strUrl);
            Credentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("", ""); 
            httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), creds);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        }
        return line;
    }

    private String downloadUrlPage(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String line = null;

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(strUrl);
            
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        }
        return line;
    }
    
    /** AsyncTask to download xml data */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTaskEx<String, Integer, String> {
        String data = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    
        // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread 
        listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
                        
        // Start parsing xml data
        listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
    }
}
```

Code for DownloadPage

```
    /** AsyncTask to download xml data */
    private class DownloadPage extends AsyncTaskEx<String, Integer, String>{
        String data = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                data = downloadUrlPage(url[0]);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            products = Integer.parseInt(Html.fromHtml(result).toString());

            Log.i("Result page", Html.fromHtml(result).toString());
        }
    }
```

Code for ScrollDownloadTask

```
/** AsyncTask to download xml data */
private class ScrollDownloadTask extends AsyncTaskEx<String, Integer, String> {
    String data = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    
        // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread 
        ScrollListViewLoaderTask ScrollListViewLoaderTask = new ScrollListViewLoaderTask();

        // Start parsing xml data
        ScrollListViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
    }
}
```

Code for ScrollListViewLoaderTaks

```
/** AsyncTask to parse xml data and load ListView */
private class ScrollListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTaskEx<String, Void, SimpleAdapter> {
    StringReader reader;
        
    // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strXml) {
        DocumentBuilder db = null;
        InputSource is = null;

        try {
            db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(strXml[0]));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("XML Exception1",e.toString());
        }

        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = db.parse(is);
        } catch (SAXException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("product");
        NodeList nodename = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");

        //fill in the list items from the XML document
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();    

            Log.i("child notes", nodename.item(i).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
            Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);

            Log.i("Manu name", "" + Integer.parseInt(XMLLoader.getValue(e, "quantity")));
            if (Integer.parseInt(XMLLoader.getValue(e, "quantity")) > 0) {
                Log.i("Stock!", "Stock!");
                map.put("stock", R.drawable.stock);
            } else {
                map.put("stock", R.drawable.nostock);
            }
            String id = XMLLoader.getValue(e, "id");
            String imageid = XMLLoader.getValue(e, "id_default_image");
            String name = nodename.item(i).getFirstChild().getTextContent();
            String newname = name;

            if (newname.contains("-") | newname.contains(".") | newname.contains("'")) {
                newname = newname.replaceAll("-", " ");
                newname = newname.replaceAll(".", " ");
                newname = newname.replaceAll("'", "");
            }
            String nameimage = newname.replaceAll(" ", "-");

            map.put("id", id);
            map.put("name", name);
            map.put("imageid", imageid);
            map.put("flag", R.drawable.tlogotrans);    
            map.put("flag_path", "http://no.nl/" + id +  "-" + imageid + "-home/" + nameimage +  ".jpg");
            // map.put("flag_path", "http://no.nl/img/p/" + id + "-" + imageid + ".jpg");
            // imageLoader.DisplayImage(, thumb);

            String p = XMLLoader.getValue(e, "price");
            String price = p.substring(0, p.length() - 4);
            map.put("price",price); 
            map.put("manufacturer_name", XMLLoader.getValue(e, "manufacturer_name"));
                    
            mylist.add(map);
        }       

        // Keys used in Hashmap 
        String[] from = { "name","manufacturer_name","price","flag","stock"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.tvPRName,R.id.tvPLMerk,R.id.tvPRPrijs,R.id.imPThumb,R.id.imstock};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item        

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), mylist, R.layout.productlijstrow, from, to);  
        return adapter;
    }
        
    /** Invoked by the Android when "doInBackground" is executed */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {
            
        // Setting adapter for the listview
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            
            
            for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
                imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();
                
                HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put("flag_path",imgUrl);
                hm.put("position", i);
                
                // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview 
           
                imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);

                
                
            }
        }       
    }
    
    
    /** AsyncTask to parse xml data and load ListView */
    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTaskEx<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

        StringReader reader;
        
        // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread 
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strXml) {
            DocumentBuilder db = null;
            InputSource is = null;
            try{
                db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                is = new InputSource();
         is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(strXml[0]));
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("XML Exception1",e.toString());
            }
            
            
            

            
            
            

                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = db.parse(is);
                } catch (SAXException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                
              
                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("product");
                
                NodeList nodename = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
                NodeList link = doc.getElementsByTagName("link_rewrite");
                
                //fill in the list items from the XML document
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();    
                    
                     
            

                    Log.i("child notes", nodename.item(i).getFirstChild().getTextContent());
                    Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);

                    Log.i("Manu name", "" + Integer.parseInt(XMLLoader.getValue(e, "quantity")));
                    
                    if(Integer.parseInt(XMLLoader.getValue(e, "quantity")) > 0){
                        Log.i("Stock!", "Stock!");
                        
                        map.put("stock", R.drawable.stock);
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    }else{
                        
                        map.put("stock", R.drawable.nostock);
                    }
                    String id = XMLLoader.getValue(e, "id");
                    String imageid = XMLLoader.getValue(e, "id_default_image");
                    String name = nodename.item(i).getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                    String newname = link.item(i).getFirstChild().getTextContent();
                    
                
                    
                    map.put("id", id);
                    map.put("name", name);
                    map.put("imageid", imageid);
                    
                    map.put("flag", R.drawable.tlogotrans);    
                    //
                    map.put("flag_path", "http://no.nl/" + id +  "-" + imageid + "-home/" + newname +  ".jpg");
                //  map.put("flag_path", "http://no.nl/img/p/" + id + "-" + imageid + ".jpg");

                //  imageLoader.DisplayImage(, thumb);

                    String p = XMLLoader.getValue(e, "price");
                    
                    String price = p.substring(0, p.length() - 4);
                    map.put("price",price );    
                    map.put("manufacturer_name", XMLLoader.getValue(e, "manufacturer_name"));
                    
                    mylist.add(map);
                    
                    
                }       

            // Keys used in Hashmap 
            String[] from = { "name","manufacturer_name","price","flag","stock"};

            // Ids of views in listview_layout
            int[] to = { R.id.tvPRName,R.id.tvPLMerk,R.id.tvPRPrijs,R.id.imPThumb,R.id.imstock};

            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item        
            
            
            adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), mylist, R.layout.productlijstrow, from, to);  
            
            return adapter;
        }
        
        /** Invoked by the Android when "doInBackground" is executed */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {
            
            // Setting adapter for the listview
        
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            
            for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
                imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();
                
                HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put("flag_path",imgUrl);
                hm.put("position", i);
                
                // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview 
                imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
            }
            
            
        }       
    }
    
    /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTaskEx<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {
            
            InputStream iStream=null;
            String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");
            
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(imgUrl);
                
                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url                
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                
                // Getting Caching directory 
                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
                
                // Temporary file to store the downloaded image 
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");               
                    
                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
                
                // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);             
                
                // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);              
                
                // Flush the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.flush();
                
                //Close the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.close();             
                
                // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                
                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());
                
                // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                hmBitmap.put("position",position);              
                
                // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
                return hmBitmap;                
                

            }catch (Exception e) {              
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
            // Getting the path to the downloaded image
            **String path = (String) result.get("flag");**          
            
            // Getting the position of the downloaded image
            int position = (Integer) result.get("position");
            
            // Getting adapter of the listview
            SimpleAdapter adaptert = (SimpleAdapter ) list.getAdapter();
            
            // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adaptert.getItem(position);  
            
            // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter 
            hm.put("flag",path);
            Log.i("Status", imageLoaderTask.getStatus().toString());
            
            if(imageLoaderTask.getStatus() == AsyncTaskEx.Status.FINISHED){
                check = 0;
            }
            // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
            adaptert.notifyDataSetChanged();    
            working = 0;    
        }   
    }
    }
```

Comment: *without* reading your code, I recommend you to initialize your variables as soon as possible! You class is full of variables pointing nowhere, what may or may not change later. See if this helps your NullPointerException.

Comment: Read your IllegalStateException, are you modifying your data from other threads? If so, msg the UI thread to update its content.

Comment: The variables does nothing about the NullPointerException, And yes I have 3 Threads as you may see one to load the Json one to put the Json in a listview and one to put the Images next to the correct products

Comment: highlight "productlijst.java:761" in your code.

Comment: It's String path = (String) result.get("flag"); Marked with ** **

Comment: I may not seeing, but where is the code from your adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the data source has been changed call the following method:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Be sure to call the method from the UI thread !

You are not calling the above method in the right place:

```
ScrollDownloadTask scrollDownloadTask = new ScrollDownloadTask();
scrollDownloadTask.execute("http://no.nl/api/products?display=full&limit=" + c + ",10&filter[id_category_default]=" + filter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Should be called when new items are loaded and added in the data source.